# Plugin like mp4parser in flutter to mix audio and video

Tags: flutter, mp4parser

I want to use mp4parser in flutter for merging video and audio. However, I can't find any plugins in Flutter. Is there any alternative available in a flutter. If not can we I write code in using mp4parser and than use it in flutter? Will it work for IOS as well?